# Why is it a “garland of sonnets”?

Tags: collocation, collective-nouns

> William Shakespeare is famous for his ________ of sonnets.

A) garland
B) collection
C) anthology
D) couplets

My future and life is depend on this question, it is not about just to tell my teacher. I missed selection in my job just by 1 mark. They gave "garland" as correct option and I challenged it by saying this question have multiple correct answers, as "collection" also fits betterly.

Kindly help me out with most correct answer.

Comment: William shakespear is famous for his sonnets.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: It's a trick question. Write in "(E) hatred". Your teacher will be impressed that you actually did the research. You can find this in his Rolling Stone interview about  "Sonnet XC": "Then hate me when thou wilt; if ever, now;". References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare, http://shakespeare.mit.edu/Poetry/sonnets.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4, and http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/sonnet/90.

Comment: My future and life is depend on this question, it is not about just to tell my teacher . I missed selection in my job just by 1 mark. They gave "garland" as correct option and i challenged it by saying this question have multiple correct answers, as "collection" also fits betterly. Kindly help me out with most correct answer

Comment: What an odd question. I took my exams in medieval and early modern literature. By scholars today, most often they're called *sonnet sequences*. Calling a sonnet sequence a *garland* is a very old-fashioned turn of phrase, and generally similar to *anthology* (in Greek a gathering of flowers) - each poem is a flower in the garland. A collection is more general than a garland, and so may be the less correct of the two in the test assessor's mind. As for Shakespeare, his first edition uses no such terms. They are Shakespeares Sonnets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wreath_of_Sonnets

Comment: Just show them [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=series+of+sonnets%2Ccollection+of+sonnets%2Csequence+of+sonnets%2Cgarland+of+sonnets&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseries%20of%20sonnets%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccollection%20of%20sonnets%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csequence%20of%20sonnets%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgarland%20of%20sonnets%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Right now there isn't enough information about the test to justify a different answer. "Garland" is an _acceptable_ answer, even if it's insufferably pretentious in actual use. Anyway, this sort of test question often depends on earlier coursework. For example, if you're being tested after some reading assignment that mentions a "garland of sonnets", it won't matter what collective noun is more commonly used, the correct answer will be "garland".

Comment: No earlier coursework or not any reading comprehension texts are given before test. It was the random question asked in english language. This question will be discareded if I give enogh proof that it have multiple correct answers. I want solid proof in the form of any document or on any website like wikepedia to prove it. I thank you everybody for answering it.

Comment: Neal, @PeterShor 's Google Ngram results should be sufficient to convince them, since it shows that "garland of sonnets" is less frequently used than "collection of sonnets".